# Pass properties in module.exports.execute(param)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, parameters, properties

How to pass properties of an parameter between files using the `async execute(args)` inside an module exports. For example:

```js
const obj = {
      conditio: true
};
<...something>.execute(obj); // obj as the param
```

and in the module.exports:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'something',
    async execute(obj) {} // here when I call the obj, the VSC will show the 'condition' as a property
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you not know what `<...something>` should be?

Comment: What do you mean by "*here when I call the obj*"? `obj` is not callable.